# In Excel how can I make sub sums when sum by group

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is a little tricky to explain. I want to make multiple sums within the same group when the value is maximum 500-800 (need to decide upon this). From row 7 to 28 I have the product category B1-2-2. In column E, i'm illustrating what I am working on.

When summing D7:D14 I get 595. I then start over again and sum the row until I get 738 which is still in the same category (B1-2-2).

As you can see from Category B1-1-2 the values are more than 500-800 and they only return their own value.

I am looking for a way to start.

[image: picture]

Comment: you will need to pivot your data

Comment: Hey! thanks for your comment. The pivot just allows me to sum on the entire group. I need multiple sums on same group. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't follow this.  How do you decide what to total?

Comment: Values under 500 will sum up to max 500  and also have to be in the same product category. So assume B1-1-1 has 10 rows with 100 in each row. Then it would be 2 rows with 500

Comment: In your example why did you pick out 595 and 738?

Comment: In my example I am using between max value 500-800. But max 500 is alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA script dif the job

```html
Sub calculateSum()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long, category As String, cost As Long, totalCost As Long, nextCost As Long
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 
 Sheets(5).Activate
   
 lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastRow
    category = Cells(i, 2)
    cost = Cells(i, 4)
    totalCost = totalCost + cost
    Cells(i, 5) = 0
    'Case : 1 Cost more than 800
    If totalCost > 800 Then
        Cells(i, 5) = cost
        totalCost = 0
    Else
    
        
        'Case : 2 Cost is less than 800
       
        If category = Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
           If (totalCost + Cells(i + 1, 4)) > 800 Then
           Cells(i, 5) = totalCost
           totalCost = 0
           End If
        Else
          Cells(i, 5) = totalCost
          totalCost = 0
        End If
        
    
    End If
    
 Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are trying to sum by grouping products of similar product categories, and then filtering this to see if the values are more than 500-800.

One way to approach this problem is to create a pivot table where your two rows would be product category, followed by product , and then your values will be the total column. You can then copy and paste the result into another table, where you can then filter by total >500-800.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. The pivot just allows me to sum the entire product category. The same as subtotals. I need a way to make sub sums within product categories. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new column after you pivot. So for each sum of Total, you create a range using Lookup. the formula is `=LOOKUP(A1,{0,"0-500";501,"500-800";10000,"800+"})`

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. Do I need to place the formula from E2:E32. When I type in the formula it returns 0-500. Is that correct?

Comment: In column F. Just drop that formula in there and let A1 change to D1. so =LOOKUP(D1,{0,"0-500";501,"500-800";10000,"800+"})

Comment: So now it returns 501 each time my values are more than 500. How do I then sum?

Comment: from your question, it seems you want to group the sum of 'Product Category'. This will mean, that  you need to do the pivot first and then create a new columm based on the value of that sum.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not how this can be solved I believe. If you look at the picture and column E you can see what I am looking for

Comment: Belive me, if you do a pivot, the value of the total sum of 'Product Category' will be the same as what you have in column E.

Comment: I have added a visual explanation to help you.

Comment: Thanks! just looked at it. Your pivot is basically just summing the groups. So B-2-1 = 900 (300+600). If you look at my example we have many sums within the same category. Look at E14 which is equal 595. That number comes from 21+60+21+31+21+30+62+349. After that we stay in the same category and continue adding numbers.

Comment: yes, yes, yes (I understand). I only showed you an example. if you pivot, which I did, it will sum ALL the 'total' in that category, it doesnt matter how many elements in that group.. That is exactly what you need - PIVOT first.